# Heading from Point A to Point B in 2D space?

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

I'm working on a project which requires me to calculate the heading from a variable point A to a variable point B in 0 - 360 degrees to let the object at point A face point B.

Now, I'm unsure on how to achieve this, I googled but didn't find any good solution.

How would I calculate the heading from point A to point B in 2D space in any situation?

Comment: Is it that you don't get the meaning of the word "heading" in this context, or that you don't quite know how to do the math?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a language such as C or C++ you might use the `atan2` function, which calculates the arctangent of y/x over four quadrants, taking the signs of x and y into account.

If A is at (x1, y1) and B is at (x2, y2), then the heading in radians is given by:

```
theta_radians = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
```

The range of `theta_radians` is -π to +π. You can convert this to degrees in the range 0 to 360 as follows:

```
theta_degrees = (theta_radians + M_PI) * 360.0 / (2.0 * M_PI);
```

[$ man atan2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atan2)

Answer (score 1):

It's trig.  You know the position of the two points and you can use them to make a right triangle.  From that you can use [SOH-CAH-TOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) to find the angle you're interested in.  Then from there you need to determine which quadrant the triangle is in and offset the computed angle appropriately.